# JS onclick() not called at all in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onclick

I've created a drop-down menu with HTML and JS. When I run it in Chrome it works great, but it doesn't work in IE. The `onclick()` function doesn't seem to be called at all.

The options tags within the select tag look like this:

```
<option value="?id=3" onclick="hideDropDown();return false;">Option 3</option>
```

but `hideDropDown()` never gets run in IE (I've checked using an alert() within the function).

The same for:

```
<option value="?id=2" onclick="alert('hi'); return false;">Option 2</option>
```

clicking on 'Option 2' in this case does not bring up an alert.

I've read a lot online about `onclick()` not working in IE, but none of the answers I've seen have worked for me. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: You should be using the `select`'s `change` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there're issues with `onclick` events in `<option>` tags. One of the alternatives would be placing an `onchange` event into the parent `<select>` tag:

```
<select onchange="check(this.value)">
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

Then `check()` function is executed every time an option is selected (clicked):

```
function check(value) {
  alert(value);
}
```

Also, you could look at the option's value to run certain code only for it:

```
function check(value) {
  if (value === 2) {
    alert("You clicked two!");
  }
}
```

---

#### Working example

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwbvbR

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand why you want to return false after function call.
Maybe you can return false from the function.

So the code will be:

```
function hideDropDown() {
  //enter code here
return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was a solution suggested on another forum as a weird and wonderful way to get around a bug I might have been pulling up in IE. I've tried what you've suggested and tried removing the 'return false' altogether but it doesn't change the result - the javascript still won't run.